# AngularJS disable filter dyamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a single page app built with angular with a `filter` that is responsible for substituting localized strings for reference keys.

**Example:**

```
{{'example.context.section.id'  | translate}}
```

I want to be able to disable the filter programmatically or overwrite it so that it just outputs the key. The point is to create a button on the mockups that allow the writers to view the translation keys their actual context.

```
angular.module('***').filter('translate', function() {
    return function(input){ return input; }
});
```

I tried just executing the above filter replacement in the console but the translations still occur using the actual translate filter.

I also tried using `$filterProvider` in a config block after-the-fact but this also had no effect. I followed the guide on the (docs)[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filterProvider] for this.

```
angular.module('ltAccountApp').config(['$filterProvider', function($filterProvider){
    $filterProvider.register('translate', function(translate) { 
        return function(input) { return input; }
    });
}]);
```

Also this variation based on the docs:

```
angular.module('ltAccountApp').run(['$provide', '$filterProvider', function($provide, $filterProvider){
    $provide.value('translate', function(input){ return input; });
    $filterProvider.register('translate', function(translate) { 
        return translate(input) || input;
    });
}]);
```

Maybe I could add the filter provider to the code and have it switch between the 2 options based on a rootscope variable?

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

*Using AngularJS 1.08*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a flag on `$rootScope` to control filter behavior.

```
angular.module('***')
.filter('translate', function($rootScope) {
  return function(input) {

    // define a `enableFilter` property in $rootScope to control filter behavior
    if ($rootScope.enableFilter) {
      // transform input here
      return transformedInput;
    } else {
      return input;
    }

  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Then how would I toggle the $rootScope variable from the console?

Comment: @ogc-nick Well, this need a little bit hack. You can assign `$rootScope` to `window` and toggle `enableFilter` with: `$rootScope.$apply(function() { $rootScope.enableFilter = !$rootScope.enableFilter; });`

Comment: A double-global hack, we better keep this on the dl. Thanks though, I'll give it a shot. It is only for a prototype anyways, not production.

Comment: Your suggestion worked but I ended up just checking an window variable for a setting instead of attaching rootscope to window.

Comment: @ogc-nick cool, there is also a `$window` service in angular, it also refers to `window` object.